# Is it possible to do variables with local scoping in c#?

Tags: c#, scala, scope

In `Scala` I can do something like this:

```
val result = {
  val a = 4
  val b = 16
  a + b
}
```

Which is basically just a (in this case immutable) variable that has its own local scoping like a method.

The following expression, however, is completely illegal in `C#`:

```
var result = 
{
    var a = 4;
    var b = 16;
    return a + b;
}
```

So the question is, is there any way I could emulate this feature, without being forced to make a `Func` or separate method?

Comment: Why you don't want to use `Func`, C# is statical language and not first class function, so I guess there are no way if you don't want to use `Func`

Comment: I don't want to use Func, because all it does is set `result` to be a function, that I can evaluate later, but `result` is not a function, it's a variable, and as such it's being evaluated immediately

Comment: See my answer of using `Func`

Comment: your answer makes a valid point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid result is delegate, you can call `Func` to run immediately after instantiating:

```
var result = new Func<int>(() => {
    var a = 4;
    var b = 16;
    return a + b;
})();
```

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is:

```
var result = 0;
{
  var a = 4;
  var b = 16;
  result = a + b;
}
```

Comment: not pretty, but it does give a and b their own local scope, so I guess that's one way to do it